Slicer with custom measure

I have powerbi report there is table with column 'course name' 'course ID' 'user ID', 'user rating' etc..
I would like to add filter (slicer) that filter data based on how many times course rated.
ex.   let's say the minimum is '10', then filter out any courses that have less than 10 time rated
so ex.
if only 9 people put a rating in for XX course, then don't show that course in the list on my visual table
I have custom measure that can give me count of rating/user but custom measure can not work as slicer
i have attached screen shot of my report,
i have an issue on 'Filter on minimum number of ratings provided' filter
